# Best word: definition or enunciate?

Tags: word-choice

Suppose a math problem like this:

A car travels one hour at 100 miles per hour. What is the travelled distance?

Suppose I am later talking about the problem.

In Portuguese I can say "De acordo com o enunciado do problema" that would translate to "According to the problem __________"

The word here is "enunciado" in Portuguese which can be directly translated to "enunciate".

Is it correct to say "according to the problem enunciate" or is the better to say... "according to the problem definition"... 
?

Comment: *Enunciado* cannot be directly translated to "enunciate". *Enunciar* can. But you wouldn't say "De acordo com o enunciar do problema" in Portuguese, would you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many common ways to phrase this.  Words like [phrasing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phrasing), [statement](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/statement), [wording](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wording), or *definition* would work, but *enunciation* would be a little odd unless referring to a speaker's unique verbal delivery.  You could even just say "According to the problem, ..."